# 'if playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device' when playing youtube video in webview and webview is in service

Tags: android, service, youtube, android-webview

you tube video is playing in web view when web view is in activity but when i use web view in service(or process) then you tube video start buffering and shows 'if playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device' message.

Video is playing in HONOR NEM-L22(OS- marshmallow) but not in other devices. I have tried in various version of android OS(lollipop, kitkat). In Sony C6802 only audio is playing, video is not visible

**Here is the code**

```
package com.appzcloud.youtube_webview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class AppopenService extends Service {
int screenwidth, screenheight;
private View myView;
LinearLayout bottm_layout;
RelativeLayout up_layout;
private WindowManager wm;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
Utilities utils;
ScreenOrientationEnforcer screenChangelistner;
///////////////////////new variables/////////////////////////////////////////
private WebView mWebView;
Button playButton, close, backward, forward, shuffle, repeat;
SeekBar seekBar;
float totalVideoDuration;
final static int MAX = 1000;
int ErrorState = 0;
int PlayerStates;
List<String> videoList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> shuffleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> listremove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String selectedVideo = "";
int selectedVideoPosition = 0, selectedVideoPositionForSuffle = 0;
boolean repeatIsOn = false, shuffleisOn = false, genrater_random_number = false, videoisPlaying=true;

/*0 (ended)                 YT.PlayerState.ENDED
1 (playing)                 YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
2 (paused)                  YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
3 (buffering)               YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING
5 (video cued).             YT.PlayerState.CUED*/
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)

{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    utils = new Utilities();
    Log.e("here we are","onCreate before inflater");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.defaultpopup, null);
    Log.e("here we are","onCreate after inflater myView"+ myView);
    playButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    close = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.cross);
    backward = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.backward);
    forward = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.forward);
    shuffle = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.suffle);
    repeat = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.repeat);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) myView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekBar.setMax(MAX);
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    screenwidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    screenheight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    screenChangelistner = new ScreenOrientationEnforcer(this);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
    params.height=screenheight/2;
    params.width=screenwidth-100;
    videoList.add("f3hINqW-Z00");
    videoList.add("G6Jpco8kKds");
    videoList.add("PT2_F-1esPk");
    videoList.add("bY_LRayav14");
    videoList.add("WPwTPhFMm3k");

    selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
    initWebView(selectedVideo);

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(myView, params);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
            double secs = (progress * totalVideoDuration) / 1000;
            secs = Math.ceil(secs);
            //Log.e("main", "onStopTrackingTouch :: progress = " + progress +  "-- secs = " + secs);
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:m_seekVideo('" + secs + "')");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.e("mainactivity", "onStartTrackingTouch :: progress = " + seekBar.getProgress() );
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(videoisPlaying) {

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"video is paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    videoisPlaying=false;
                    playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_1);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:m_pauseVideo()");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else
            if(!videoisPlaying) {

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"video is played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    videoisPlaying=true;
                    playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_1);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:m_playVideo()");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(AppopenService.this,"close button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:m_pauseVideo()");
            wm.removeView(myView);
            stopSelf();
        }
    });

    backward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(AppopenService.this,"backward button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            previousVideo();
    }
    });

    forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(AppopenService.this,"forward button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nextVideo();
        }
    });

    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(AppopenService.this,"shuffle button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (shuffleisOn) {

                shuffleisOn = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "shuffle is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                genrater_random_number = false;
                generateRandomNumber();
                if (repeatIsOn) {
                    repeatIsOn = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "repeat is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                shuffleisOn = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "shuffle is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    repeat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(AppopenService.this,"repeat button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (repeatIsOn) {
                repeatIsOn = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "repeat is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (shuffleisOn) {
                    shuffleisOn = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "shuffle is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                repeatIsOn = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "repeat is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

void generateRandomNumber() {
    if (genrater_random_number == false) {
        genrater_random_number = true;
        shuffleList.clear();
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ videos_play_next_list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < videoList.size(); i++)
        {
            shuffleList.add(i);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+i+"times "+shuffleList.add(i) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + shuffleList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (shuffleList.contains(selectedVideoPosition)) {

            int index = shuffleList.indexOf(selectedVideoPosition);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "index of zero is "+index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //listremove.add(shuffleList.get(index));
            shuffleList.remove(index);
        }
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+list , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);
        shuffleList.add(0, selectedVideoPosition);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + shuffleList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void nextVideo() {
    if (repeatIsOn) {
        if (selectedVideo == videoList.get(4)) {
            selectedVideoPosition = 0;

        } else {
            selectedVideoPosition++;
        }
        selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
    playvideo(selectedVideo);
    } else if (shuffleisOn) {
        //generateRandomNumber();
        if (selectedVideoPositionForSuffle < videoList.size() - 1) {
            selectedVideoPositionForSuffle++;
            selectedVideoPosition = shuffleList.get(selectedVideoPositionForSuffle);
            selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
            playvideo(selectedVideo);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List of video finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        if (selectedVideo == videoList.get(4)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "last Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            selectedVideoPosition++;
            selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
            playvideo(selectedVideo);
        }
    }
}

private void previousVideo() {
    if (repeatIsOn) {
        if (selectedVideo == videoList.get(0)) {
            selectedVideoPosition = videoList.size() - 1;

        } else {
            selectedVideoPosition--;
        }
        selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
        playvideo(selectedVideo);
    } else if (shuffleisOn) {
        //generateRandomNumber();
        if (selectedVideoPositionForSuffle > 0) {
            selectedVideoPositionForSuffle--;
            selectedVideoPosition = shuffleList.get(selectedVideoPositionForSuffle);
            selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
            playvideo(selectedVideo);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "starting of video list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        if (selectedVideo == videoList.get(0)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "first Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            selectedVideoPosition--;
            selectedVideo = videoList.get(selectedVideoPosition);
            playvideo(selectedVideo);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "JavascriptInterface"})
private void initWebView(String string) {
    Log.e("here we are","initWebView Method");
    mWebView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.setClickable(false);
    mWebView.setFocusable(false);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    //settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
    mWebView.setLayerType(2, null);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(AppopenService.this), "JSHandler");
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromwClient());
    playvideo(string);
}

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("main", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : url = " + url);

        if (url.contains("onStateChange")) {
            String arr[] = {};
            arr = url.split("=");
            //int x=Integer.parr[0].toString();
            if (arr[1].matches("[0-9]+") && arr[1].length() >= 1) {
                PlayerStates = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

                //Log.d("main", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : url = " + arr[1]);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+PlayerStates,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadin", "getting player state is " + PlayerStates);

            if (PlayerStates == 0) {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadin", "PlayerStates=0");
                modifySlider("ENDED");
                nextVideo();
            }

            if (PlayerStates == 3) {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadin", "PlayerStates=3");
                seekBar.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadin", "PlayerStates=2");
                seekBar.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        if (url.contains("onPlayTime")) {

            if (PlayerStates == 1) {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadin", "PlayerStates=1");
                String arr[] = {};
                arr = url.split("=");
                //  Log.d("main", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : url = " + arr[1]);

                try {
                    changeSlider(Float.parseFloat(arr[1]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private class MyChromwClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  Log.e("main", "consoleMessage : " + consoleMessage.message());
        try {
            if (consoleMessage.message().matches("[0-9]+") && consoleMessage.message().length() >= 1)
            {
                totalVideoDuration = Float.parseFloat(consoleMessage.message());
                Log.e("charcter at value==", "sdn" + totalVideoDuration);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
    }
}

private class MyJavaScriptInterface {

public AppopenService activity;

public MyJavaScriptInterface(AppopenService activity) {

    this.activity = activity;
}

    public void setVideoDuration(String duration) {

        try {
            Log.e("main", "setVideoDuration = " + duration);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            changeSlider(Float.parseFloat(duration));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setTotalVideoDuration(String duration) {
        Log.e("main", "setTotalVideoDuration = " + duration);

        try {
            totalVideoDuration = Float.parseFloat(duration);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //}
    public void videoEnd() {
        modifySlider("ENDED");
    }
}

public void playvideo(String videostring)
{
    String html = "";
    html += "<html>"+"<head>"+"<body>"+"<style>"+"body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }"+
            "html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }"+
            ".embed-container iframe,"+
            ".embed-container object,"+
            ".embed-container embed {"+
            "position: absolute;"+
            "top: 0;"+
            "left: 0;"+
            "width: 100%% !important;"+
            "height: 100%% !important;"+
            "}"+
            "</style>"+
            "</head>"+"<body>"+"<div class=embed-container>"+"<div id=ytplayer></div>"+"</div>"+"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>"+"<script type='text/javascript'>"+
            "var vID;"+
            "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()"+
            "{"+
            "ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{"+
            "events:{"+
            "'onReady': onPlayerReady,"+
            "'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,"+
            "'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerQualityChange,"+
            "'onError': onPlayerError"+
            "}"+
            "});"+
            "}"+"function onPlayerReady(event)"+"{"+
            "event.target.playVideo();"+
            "setTotalVideoDuration();"+
            "}"+
            "function onPlayerStateChange(event)"+"{"+
            "window.location.href ='ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;"+

            "}"+
            "function onPlayerQualityChange(event)"+"{"+
            "window.location.href ='ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;"+
            "}"+
            "function onPlayerError(event)"+
            "{"+
            "window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onError?data=' + event.data;"+
            "}"+

            "function m_stopVideo()"+"{"+

            "ytplayer.stopVideo();"+
            "}"+

            "function m_playVideo() {"+

            "ytplayer.playVideo();"+
            "}"+

            "function m_pauseVideo()"+ "{"+
            "ytplayer.pauseVideo();"+
            "}"+

            "function m_seekVideo(time){"+

            "ytplayer.seekTo(time, true);"+
            "}"+
            "function  setTotalVideoDuration(){"+
            //return player.getDuration();
            "console.log(ytplayer.getDuration());"+
        /*"JSHandler.setTotalVideoDuration(ytplayer.getDuration());"+*/
            "}"+
            "function onPlayTime(time){"+

        /*"JSHandler.setVideoDuration(time);"+*/

            "}"+
            "function getCurrentTime() {"+
            "var state = ytplayer.getPlayerState();"+
            "if (state == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {"+
            "time = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();"+
            "window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlayTime?data=' + time;"+
            "onPlayTime(time);"+
            "}"+
            "}"+

            "window.setInterval(getCurrentTime, 1000);"+
            "function m_loadVideo(vidID)"+"{"+
            "vID=vidID;"+
            "ytplayer.loadVideoById(vID, 0, '"+"large"+"');"+
            "setTotalVideoDuration();"+
            "}"+

            "</script>";

    /// set video id                                                                                                here
    html +=" <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%%' height='100%%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videostring+"?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&fs=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&vq=medium&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1' frameborder=0></iframe>";
    html += "</body></html>";

    // mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);

    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
}

private void changeSlider(float time) {
    float progress = (time / totalVideoDuration) * 1000;
    final double d = Math.ceil(progress);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBar.setProgress((int) d);
}

private void modifySlider(final String flag)
{
    if (flag.equals("ENDED"))
        seekBar.setProgress(MAX);
}

/////////////////////previous code//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLowMemory();
    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," low memory call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," task remov yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.e("here we are","onStartCommand");

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
}
```

I have taken various permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

I neither could find the issue nor the solution. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens to me even in a Fragment or Activity.  But it only happens on certain APIs.  For example, API 23 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in setting the webview.
Then i used webview like this.

```
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "JavascriptInterface"})
private void initWebView(String string) {
   mWebView.setClickable(false);
    mWebView.setFocusable(false);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    } else {
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    }
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
    mWebView.setLayerType(2, null);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromwClient());
    playvideo(string);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(PopupiTune.this), "JSHandler");
}
```

and the webview started playing youtube videos.